# Create nested form rails controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

How can I use the controller to update my new field I added?
Below is my code.

This is `edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @drama, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.nested_fields_for :trailerlinks do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.remove_nested_fields_link %>
    <%= ff.text_field :name %>

     <%= f.add_nested_fields_link :trailerlinks %>

  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the controller like this:

```
def create
@drama = Drama.friendly.find(params[:drama_id])
@link = @drama.trailerlinks.new(drama_params)

    if @link.save
        flash[:success] = "Your drama was created succesfully."
        redirect_to drama_path(@drama)
    else
        render :new
    end

end

def update
  i = 0
  until i = 1
    @link = @drama.trailerlinks.new(trailer_params[:trailerlinks]["#{i}"])
    @link.save
    i += 1
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @link.save
    flash[:success] = "Your trailer was edited 123." 
  end
end

private

def trailer_params
  params.require(:trailerlink).permit(:name, :traurl)
end
```

`Drama` Model:

```
class Drama < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trailerlinks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trailerlinks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

`Trailerlink` Model:

```
class Trailerlink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drama
end
```

Comment: What exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

immediate problem is `until i = 1` which should be `until i == 1`. However why do you need to run the loop? Because if `add_nested_fields_link` work properly in your form, your application should be able to infer what's a new record and an old record and you should be able to do something like:

```
def update
  if @drama.update(drama_params)
   # do something here, it saved
  else
   # do something else, it failed
  end
end

private
  def drama_params
    params.require(:drama).permit(trailerlinks_attributes: [:name, :traurl])
  end
```

**UPDATE**
To allow destroy and update of existing records, you could do:

```
  def drama_params
    params.require(:drama).permit(trailerlinks_attributes: [:name, :traurl, :id, :_destroy])
  end
```

Comment: why unknown attribute 'trailerlinks_attributes' for Trailerlink?

Comment: [1] pry(#<TrailerlinksController>)> trailer_params
Unpermitted parameter: trailerlinks_attributes
=> {}
[2] pry(#<TrailerlinksController>)>

Comment: how about `params`?

Comment: `drama_params` not `trailer_params` BTW.

Comment: "drama"=>
  {"trailerlinks_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"name"=>"Trailer 1",
       "traurl"=>"https://www.youtube.com/",
       "id"=>"3"},
     "1"=>
      {"name"=>"Trailer 2",
       "traurl"=>"https://www.youtube.com/"}}},
 "commit"=>"Update Drama",
 "controller"=>"trailerlinks",
 "action"=>"update",

Comment: so need add to drama controller or trailer link controller the drama_params?

Comment: I guess this ^^ is the `params`? Can you try `@drama.update(drama_params)`?

Comment: No you don't necessarily need to add another controller.

Comment: also unknown attribute 'trailerlinks_attributes' for Trailerlink.

Comment: can you check that your `@drama` isn't an instance of `Trailerlink`?

Comment: can already, have another problem is i add one record then, existing record also add in, now have 3 record?

Comment: It works then? Updating my answer to reflect the change to be made on the `drama_params`.

Comment: if i delete one record then click update, how can do it?

Comment: i updated my create controller above, i don no why i have this error:No route matches [PATCH]